# Can we create Snowflake External Stage pointing to a public s3 bucket without keys?

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to ingest some data into Snowflake from a public s3 bucket using external stage. I able to access the data thru the browser but when creating an external stage to query the data in Snowflake I get an "Access denied" error as I don't supply any AWS keys in the external stage creation.

My question is, Can we create Snowflake External Stage pointing to a public s3 bucket without keys?

If not, what would be the efficient and fastest way to load data from a public s3 into snowflake?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an external stage without keys:

```
CREATE or replace STAGE gdelt URL = 's3://gdelt-open-data/events/';


ls @gdelt;


select $1 from @gdelt limit 1;
```

If you are getting Access denied error, then please check if the s3 bucket is open to public.